# Outlook plugin new mail information C#

Tags: c#, outlook-addin

I am working on an outlook plug-in. Now, I have a requirement to know the attached file name, size and possible then the content of mail before downloading the mail in the outlook.  So, we can take action accordingly and delete the mail then and there. 
I know the new mail event is fired from Outlook when a new mail arrived. So, this event is suites for me or not? I don’t know whether it’s fired after download before to download?
Please help me on this.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It's fired after download (when the new mail item is actually in your inbox).

Based on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb147645%28office.12%29.aspx):

> The NewMail event fires when new
>   messages arrive in the Inbox and
>   before client rule processing occurs.
>   If you want to process items that
>   arrive in the Inbox, consider using
>   the ItemAdd event on the collection of
>   items in the Inbox. The ItemAdd event
>   passes a reference to each item that
>   is added to a folder.